# Statut incertain de « pilée »

Tags: vocabulaire, argot, régionalismes

Dans l'interview suivante, à [2h52m30s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQb1e2Bvv-A&t=10350s), on peut entendre ce qui suit.

> … de Churchill ils avaient avancé leur grande offensive …tout ça on était assez au courant hein … leur grande offensive parce que les officiers [XXX] … étaient en train … risquaient de prendre une pilée à l'ouest …

Il est à peu près certain que le mot « pilée » est utilisé dans cette phrase, et il est donc reconnu comme étant un substantif. Il n'y a pas de problème pour cette forme en tant que participe passé du verbe « piler » ou comme adjectif.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/piler)) Pilé, -ée, part. passé adj.Réduit en petits morceaux, en menus fragments. Glace pilée. Il voulait faire des articles de combat, après lesquels le monde tout entier ne serait plus que du verre pilé (Renard,Journal, 1893, p.159).

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pil%C3%A9e))

On trouve le substantif « pile », qui est très proche et qui signifie ce que l'on peut supposer.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pile)) Pop. et fam.
> A. − Volée de coups, raclée. Synon. pop. et fam. dérouillée, trempe, rossée (vieilli).Avec ça qu'il n'en a pas fait bien d'autres, lui! (...) qui flanquait des piles aux évêques sur la porte de leurs propres cathédrales! (Gyp,Profess. lover, 1894, p.194).

Est-ce que ce mot, « pilée », qu'il faudrait prendre comme synonyme de « pile » selon toute apparence, serait une  forme régionale, de l'argot, ou bien un terme familier du français qui aurait échappé aux dictionnaires ?

Si c'est un terme régional où est-il utilisé ?

Comment: ça ressemble à une variation sur le thème : branlée, raclée, peignée. Jamais entendu pour ma part, mais *pile* non plus.

Comment: J'ai toujours entendu se prendre une pilée, je ne savais pas que ce n'est pas dans les dicos. C'est assez courant,  surtout dans le monde du sport,  [Alors que son club venait de se prendre une pilée monumentale en finale](https://www.20minutes.fr/sport/2259691-20180422-video-coupe-roi-commis-erreur-nzonzi-excuse-etre-sorti-apres-debacle-face-barca),mais pas seulement, au jeu, etc.  Se prendre la raclée, se prendre une pâtée, ....

Comment: Faut regarder à piler dans le TLF : Piler Fam: Administrer une raclée; battre à plate couture. donc substantif fait à partir du participe passé.  Et je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec [cette interprétation](https://www.notos.co/albums/s8TLcwPf85?locale=fr).

Comment: En tant que "vieu" (né circa 1973) parigo j'ai entendu les deux formes (se prendre un pile ou une pilée). Pas fréquent, mais ça fait partie du vocabulaire de mon biome.

Comment: @Madlozoz « Pilée » serait peut-être plus courant à Paris. Soit dit en passant, « [pile](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pile) » est féminin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est une expression courante pour moi [aussi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49547/statut-incertain-de-pil%C3%A9e#comment101552_49547) qui a effectivement échappé aux dictionnaires, alors même que la plus ancienne trace écrite que j'ai trouvée est celle d'un immortel...

> Ils se préparent à évacuer la ville, après avoir pris une pilée à Nicolaeff et à Kherson.
> Henri Troyat, *Le sac et la cendre*, 1948